# Tag size is not correctly rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have created a reusable heading tag to implement in my Nextjs app. it shows the correct tag name in while dubbing but it does not show any difference on any level of tag.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Heading = ({ level, children, className }) => {
    const HeadingTag = `h${level}`;

    return (
        <HeadingTag
            className={`text-xl md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl font-bold ${className}`}
        >
            {children}
        </HeadingTag>
    );
};

Heading.propTypes = {
    level: PropTypes.oneOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    className: PropTypes.string
};

Heading.defaultProps = {
    className: ''
};

export default Heading;
```

and I am using like this

```
<Heading level={6}> I'm Software Developer </Heading>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Headings are unstyled in Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#headings-are-unstyled), so you won't see any visual differences.

You can either [dynamically add different classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) for each level, or [add bases styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles) if you want them to look different.